# SQL - multiple tables in search form

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with my SQL code. Here it is:

```
SELECT fur.*, cat.overskrift, cat.ikon, cat.id AS categoryID, cat.language AS catLang

      FROM furniture AS fur

      LEFT JOIN furniture_translated AS fur_tra
      ON fur_tra.furniture_id = fur.id

      LEFT JOIN furniture_categories_translated AS fur_cat_tra
      ON ((fur_cat_tra.category_id = fur.category AND fur_cat_tra.language = '".beforeDB($user_language)."')
      OR (fur_cat_tra.category_id = fur_tra.category AND fur_cat_tra.language = '".beforeDB($user_language)."'))

      LEFT JOIN furniture_categories AS cat
      ON (
        (fur.category = cat.id AND cat.language = '".beforeDB($user_language)."')
      OR
        (fur_tra.category = cat.id AND fur_cat_tra.language = '".beforeDB($user_language)."')
      )

      WHERE
        (fur.language = '".beforeDB($user_language)."' OR fur_tra.language = '".beforeDB($user_language)."')
      AND
      (
        ((cat.heading LIKE '%".beforeDB($search)."%' AND cat.language = '".beforeDB($user_language)."') OR (fur_cat_tra.heading LIKE '%".beforeDB($search)."%' AND fur_cat_tra.language = '".beforeDB($user_language)."'))
        OR
        (
          (fur.name LIKE '%".beforeDB($search)."%')
        OR
          (fur_tra.name LIKE  '%".beforeDB($search)."%')
        )
      )

      ORDER BY
      cat.heading ASC, fur.name ASC
```

beforeDB is a function I've made in PHP.. it returns the value in mysql_real_escape_string()..
$search is the string entered by the user when searching.
$user_language is the language code of the visitor.

What the website is:
The website have a list of furniture, and is a multi-language website. The furniture and categories should be translated. There should be a possibility to change the category from each language. An example: I want the possibility to put a shelf in the kitchen category in the english version, and let it be in the bathroom category in the german version.

What I want to achieve:
Have a search option for the users to easily find furniture they're looking for. They should search for the furniture on THEIR language.

What the problem is:
If I translate a furniture I still can search for the english name, when it's translated to another language. If I have, for instance, german as my language, and I searched for the english name; I would get the furniture listed in german after an english search. That should not be possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can just search in one langue at a time. Most people just speaks one language and even multilingual users (usually) do a different search for each language since not only words changes but entire context. Are you sure you must stick with that multi-langue search requirement?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading all of that correctly, you can probably force the "non-english" results to come before English with an extra `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY
   fur_tra.language = beforeDB($user_language) DESC,
   cat.header, fur.name
```

The new clause will evaluate to a simple boolean true/false, which MySQL will treat as `1` and `0` for ordering purposes. So any results that match the user's selected language will come out as `1`, and get ordered first via the DESC ordering.

Comment: I don't want to force the non-english results to come before english results.. I want to ONLY show the results for your language..

Comment: then why search on the untranslated results at all, then? Search on the fur_tra only.

Comment: Because the original furniture data is in the fur table. I want to get it, because something of the data is not changeable between the languages. I could add the furniture in the fur table when translating it; I know.. the reason for it is because then the translated furniture will have another ID, and I would use unnecessary MB's of data in the database..

Comment: storage space is cheap... if a couple extra megs break your hosting, then you really should upgrade hosting.

Comment: It does not break my hosting.. but I find it really annoying that I have to add the translated furniture with a language field in the same table. When updating the common data between the translated and the original furniture; I would have to update every field in the table.. for instance if I would want to change the image (which is not editable between translated/original furniture).

Comment: so why not put the translation text into a seperate table. common stuff (size/price/color/shape/whatever) goes into "furniture", and then the text bits that need to be translated to into a seperate "furniture_localized" table that has "furniture_id, language, field_name, localized_text" type thing.  This would have at least one record for EVERY bit of furniture (english), and extra records for ever language you have a translation for. then you never get english, because it'd be exluded by the `language = $user_language` comparisons.